# Swift UIActionSheet with left side icon and right side check mark

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create `UIActionSheet` with Left side Icon and Title Left Alignment with Right Side check mark selection. Here, I am using below code for adding Image I can't able to reduce size of the Image also Text Left alignment and check mark. How to do this?

My Code Below

```
let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)


    let documentsActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Documents", style: .default, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(documentsActionButton)
    documentsActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile"), forKey: "image")
    documentsActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

    let cameraActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cameraActionButton)
    cameraActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile"), forKey: "image")
    cameraActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

    let galleryActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(galleryActionButton)
    galleryActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile"), forKey: "image")
    galleryActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

    actionSheetAlertController.view.tintColor = UIColor .red
    self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: sample Image]

Comment: Don't touch use API, your app may reject from Appstore. Use you own custom action sheet instead

Comment: @ Mojtaba Hosseini think this is good one https://github.com/danielsaidi/Sheeeeeeeeet

Comment: @BenDev You can use that "danielsaidi/Sheeeeeeeeet" library...

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad. I tried that. Its very complex to understand.

Comment: I don't test that before. Seems ok. But you can build one from scratch. It's not that hard.

Comment: If you dont want use any pods look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557540/add-image-to-actionsheet-and-put-it-to-right/56559459#56559459