# Why am I getting Nil Layout Anchor warning while presenting my custom UIAlert?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uialertcontroller

I have a custom UIAlert where I set the content view controller to my own custom VC. The alert functions properly, but I keep getting this error: "A constraint factory method was passed a nil layout anchor". I suspect it has something to do with how I am adding my subviews, but I have tried to constrain them to no avail. Here is the code:

```
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 150)
    let sortByPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 150))
    sortByPicker.tag = 1
    sortByPicker.delegate = self
    sortByPicker.dataSource = self

    vc.view.addSubview(sortByPicker)

    let editRadiusAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sort Projects By...", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    editRadiusAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
    editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil))
    editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(editRadiusAlert, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you set your `contentViewController` before the parent view controller (the alert controller) has been added to the view hierarchy.

As you probably know if you use this hack, `contentViewController` is a private property and you're not supposed to access / set it. If you do so, you shouldn't be surprised if things don't work as expected or suddenly break in the future.

If you really wanna go with it, I suggest you follow [Leo Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092411/2062785) and subclass `UIAlertController`. If you then assign your `contentViewController` in `viewDidLoad()`, everything should be set up properly, including the parent's layout anchors.

Comment: I appreciate your input, I did not realize accessing a private API was a big no-no... but the more I read the more I am leaning away from tinkering with it. Is it true that Apple will reject app if I access a private API?

Comment: As far as I know, if they figure it out → yes. But even if they didn't it's a bad practice because they can change / rename it anytime without you knowing and then you app might stop working / crashes.

Comment: I decided to create a custom VC that mimics the alert VC. I really do appreciate it, I was overlooking this and I would've been distressed if it was rejected for this reason.